Windows Passkey shows unkown device
I'm using a Passkey via Windows to secure my Google Account. However, on setting up i noticed that there is a device that i do not recognize.

I've already been to https://account.microsoft.com/devices, but none of the mobile devices (Pixel 6a = mine, OnePlus Nord = unknown) is on that page.
Why is this device showing up? How can i remove it?

In order for a device to show up in that list it must be near the computer in order to be detected. Furthermore, you should be looking at your Google account, not your Microsoft account for the device. Why are you removing sensitive information about the device?

I don't think so. I went to the library, and came home, and on both places it shows up.

The MS passkey is independent of Google as far as i know (also because the same screen with the same devices pops up on e.g. Github when using passkeys). I am removing the device because it's not mine?

Have you checked your Google account to see which Passkeys exist?

So I am still fairly confident the two devices are coming from Google not Microsoft. Google within your Account will list Passkeys. I suspect when you check your Google account you will discover you have two Passkeys configured.

I don't. They are note coming from Google. :/

Have you looked at Settings?
